# Forgot email associated with my itunes account

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to find out what email address is used on an itunes account. I have my password but can't remember the email address! Help please!!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look in your keychain.

/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app

Select the **Login** keychain in the top left panel and the **All items** in the bottom one.
Use the search in the top right corner.
Search for iCloud, MobileMe ,iMessage or Apple ID.

Double click any of the items that come up and see if the jog you memory.
Most of these will bring up the email for your apple id.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought anything from the store with this account, just select the matching file in iTunes, press <kbd>Cmd-I</kbd> to access the info window and go to the first tab (Overview). Your Apple ID should get displayed there.